# Odds of two people having the same score in fantasy football

Tags: probability

I am trying to figure out what the odds of two people having the same the same score in our fantasy football league. Both teams ended up with a score of 104.64.

I looked back at the history of our league and the highest score ever was 224.52 and the lowest score ever was 64.02. So technically there are 16,051 realistic different scores that we could score on any given week. I am just wondering what the odds of two people getting the same score. I did 1/16501 * 1/16501 but i think that gives me the odds of two people getting a score of 104.64 and not necessarily just tying with any number in that range.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You are almost correct: the probability you computed is that exactly two players get exactly 104.64. You have to take in account multiple player pairs. I suggest you take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem

Comment: Not enough information.  To do the problem, it's probably safe to assume independence (hard to see what else one would do without just reviewing the data).  And then you'd want to see each "realistic" score along with the probability of getting it.  Also, it's not clear what you are asking for.  Are you just asking about two specific players or are you asking about the probability of at least one match among a large group?

Comment: If all the scores were equally likely the chance of a match for one pair of people would be $1/16501$, not the square as the first person's score could be anything.  In practice, is it really possible that every increment of $0.01$ is possible?  Then if you have $n$ people there are about $n^2/2$ ways to match so it gets likely quickly.  This is the essence of the birthday problem.

Comment: Correction on my comment (I cannot edit it): by "exactly two players" I meant "I a group composed of only two players"